Visual Studio thread execution stops on a non-breakpoint
I have a MAUI application, which has two different runtimes (? idk what to call this where I can choose either the Windows or Android version, nor what to call it when I choose one vs the other),

and depending on which one I pick and whether I choose to run the app in my tablet, the code will stop in a thread like so

and I have no idea why it always stops here in debug mode. I do not have a breakpoint here.
I can click "continue" to move past it with no problem. In other parts of my code where it stops like this, I have to "continue" multiple times as multiple different threads will stop at the same spot.
I looked up similar issues to this, and there is a SO post from 10 years ago, but it's not entirely the same thing since it didn't appear to have anything to do with threading. Most of my research found posts where VS is supposed to hit a breakpoint but doesn't. This is the reverse problem: threads are breaking execution where there is no breakpoint. Why does this happen and how do I get it to stop?

Are you sure "break when thrown" is not turned on in the exception settings panel?

i sometimes get the same behavior when i change code during debugging, which moves the break point line. then it can happen that VS leaves the breakpoint in the original line even after i remove it. it usual goes away after a restart. could your problem be similar?

The word you are looking for in this context is platform  or target platform.

Could this be due to an exception instead? Check whether you have something suspicious in the output pane and please post the stack trace.

I figured it out. I have (for me) an unusual set up - mainly b/c of my boss. We have 4 solutions where the MAUI solution depends on a base/core solution that has some functionality that has breakpoints set there. So even though that dependency in the other solution isn't showing, the dependent code has a breakpoint on it, which the thread catches, and breaks there, but I'm not seeing that directly in the other solution. It didn't occur to me that this might be the issue when I posted my question.
How I figured this out was based on the suggestions from @Molbac and @JonasH - I looked at the method that is referenced by this call (by opening up that specific file from the other solution in my MAUI solution) and saw that I have a breakpoint there. Removed the breakpoint and voila! The thread doesn't stop execution anymore.
tldr; breakpoint exists in a dependency in another solution that is called by the method shown.

The greenish-blue (or whatever color that is) highlighting is a clue that something is going on lower in the stack. You can see this in another case: when a breakpoint hits in your own code, you can go to the Stack Trace window and select a different stack frame from the one you are in.
It's likely a Debugger.Break() in the dependency's code. That is poor form on the author to leave it there, even more so in multi-threading scenarios. At the least the dependency code should check if the debugger is attached and/or have some runtime boolean variable that can be set to cause the breakpoint or avoid it.
Some (unsatisfying) ways to get it to stop if you don't have the source code (though I note that you seem to because you were able to remove the breakpoint yourself):

decompile the assembly, strip the breakpoints out, recompile (may not be possible, especially if the assembly is strong named. Also time consuming.
ask the author to change it!
probably the best: even in your Debug builds, reference the Release assemblies.

Side note,

I have a MAUI application, which has two different runtimes (? idk what to call this where I can choose either the Windows or Android version, nor what to call it when I choose one vs the other)

As @Wyck says in the comments, Platform and Target Platform are generally the verbiage to use here. Conversationally, you could also say OS, but platform is usually OS+Version with a Runtime (x64, x32) and/or particular SDK.
